# How can I get DeviceInformation from GattCharacteristic on ValueChanged

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a UWP app that connects to BLE devices. I have it connecting and subscribing to a characteristic. When I get the ValueChanged callback it works great, but I need to get the device ID.

I need this because my app might connect to more than one of the same type of device and want to subscribe to the same characteristic.

Since the code to get the ValueChanged notification is the same for all devices, I need a way to differentiate which device sent the ValueChanged.

Comment: The first event parameter is the GattCharacteristic. It has Service (GattDeviceService type) property. The Service has Device and DeviceId properties. By the way, it is always great to take a look at the docs before asking the question (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattcharacteristic.service?view=winrt-22000).

Comment: I did look at the docs and apparently didn't follow the chain that you just described. I spent about a half hour looking at the docs before posting this. I don't know if that shows I am even more dense that I couldn't find it. Either that or the docs do not lend themselves to finding this type of information very well.

Comment: The info can be found by just googling "GattCharacteristic". The first link opens the GattCharacteristic class description. Expanding its events you can find the ValueChanged event description with all parameters described. Simple looking on its properties gives all the required details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Mike Petrichenko's comment, you could get the device ID value like this:

```
 private async void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        GattDeviceService service = sender.Service;
        String deviceID = service.DeviceId;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear in my reply to Mike. His solution worked. I was just explaining why I felt so stupid, but that I did do a search of the docs before posting this so you know I didn't just post the question here without any research first. I have the solution and it is working great. Should I allow Mike to post his answer and accept it or just accept yours as the answer? I want to make sure Mike gets credit for his answer.